# When does the warranty for my iPad begin?

Tags: ipad

When does the warranty start for my iPad?

I heard it's when you "register" it with Apple, i.e.: when you start using it and sign in with your Apple ID.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Warranty Period is defined as

> a period of ONE (1) YEAR from the date of original retail purchase by the end-user purchaser

which is purchase date, not first use date.

https://www.apple.com/uk/legal/warranty/products/uk-ireland-universal-warranty.html

Check your own country warranty in case it’s different.

Comment: Hi, that doesn't seem to be the case.  I just received an iPad and activated it (entered the Apple ID and set up) and checked the warranty in https://checkcoverage.apple.com/  it's exactly one year from today.    In fact I purchased the iPad 8 days ago from a "black market" site (which is why it took this long to arrive).
So the Warranty seems to start when you activate the device.

Comment: That's for UK @grg